# where can I check assigned phisical IPAddress on FXOS cli and is that possible to access GUI of FXOS?

Tags: cli, cisco-firepower

I am a newbie of my companie's Network department and my boss wants me to check the IP-ADDRESS of each port of our Firepower of cisco.

We have two models of it, one is 4100 series and another is 2100 series.

I tried to find how to check those IP but I don't know where to.

maybe I need to enter somewhere like eth-uplink or something but not sure about that.

can you teach me where should I check?
and is there a way to access GUI mode of FXOS like ISE server does?

If it's possible can you teach me how to do it too?

Comment: If you need additional information that I didn't cover in my answer, @Myung Seok Kang Myun, feel free to update your question or reply. If the answer I gave was helpful, please mark your question answered so it will stop appearing to need a further answer.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

FXOS on the 4100 model line is managed by Firepower Management Center (appliance or virtual machine installation) or, on some ASA and FP2100 models, a local Firepower Device Manager installation on the device. The 4100 has to be managed by the Firepower Management Center virtual machine or appliance.

The Firepower Management Center (Now renamed Secure Firewall Management Center... for some reason) has a lot of its own features and documentation:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/660/configuration/guide/fpmc-config-guide-v66/device_management_basics.html

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/firesight-management-center/datasheet-c78-736775.html

There are limited management features on CLI or console:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/fxos/2111/web-guide/b_GUI_FXOS_ConfigGuide_2111.html

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/fxos/fxos201/cli-config/b_CLI_ConfigGuide_FXOS_201/interface_management.html